# Getting values from form as query criteria

Tags: mysql, ms-access-2013

I have a library database. There are some kind of data (books, magazines and etc.). [image]

I have a form on base of report of these data. In this example I'm trying to add in combobox just one value - Name of the book. I'm doing it by such a query in row source of the combobox:

```
SELECT [Forms]![books_list]![name] AS id;
```

books_list - the name of the form and name is the text box called name.
It returns only the first name of the book in all comboboxes - 123.
I need to show only these name values in different comboboxex, which has reference by the row.
To make it clearer - in first combobox - 123, second - Прошлое, third - May be next time.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to take the value from the text box name, and use a query to select the same value in the combo box?

```
SELECT <insert your column name here>
FROM <insert your table name here>
GROUP BY <insert your column name here>
HAVING ((<insert column name here>)=[Forms]![books_list]![name] AS id);
```

Comment: I don"t know what's the reason, but this returns the same result as mine code does. It adds to all combobox the name of the first row only. No others.

Comment: Strange. It updates when I switch from design view (also include watching and running the query code) and going back. Then it adds to all fields the value of the row from what i had started switching.

Comment: And also when I choose some value - this value is selecting in all other comboboxes.

Comment: Are you using continuous forms?

Comment: I think yes. Probably yes